# Python reading names from a csv file into a dictionary and adding a value 0 for each name

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am having trouble creating a dictionary in Python from a csv file of player names. Below is an example of my code:

```
playerNames = []
with open(player_names) as csvfile
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile)
        playerNames.append(row)
```

This bit of code will basically read the names from the csv file and put them into a nested list that looks like this:  [[P1], [P2], [P3], [P4]]

Now i'm wanting to add these player names into a dictionary as well as, add a value 0 for each player in the dictionary, the desired outcome will look something like this: {P1:0, P2:0, P3:0, P4:0} however, I am struggling to do this and would greatly appreciate some help. I also wanted to ask if it is possible to read the player names straight into the dictionary as oppose to reading them into a list first?

Any help with this or some example code would be greatly appreciated as I am new to using dictionaries

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each player's name appears just once in the input file:

```
player_dict = {}
with open('player_names.txt') as players:
    for line in players:
        player_dict[line.strip()]=0

print(player_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'larry': 0, 'tom': 0, 'dick': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `playerNames = []` with `playerNames = {}` and `playerNames.append(row)` with `playerNames[row[0]] = 0`. And "adding" 0 isn't quite the right term: you're *assigning* a zero to each key.

Answer (score 0):

With the nested lists of names, you could use the following:

```
playerDict = dict.fromkeys([p[0] for p in playerNames, 0])
```

or even:

```
playerDict = {p[0]:0 for p in playerNames}
```

I would advise however that you make only a list of names (instead of a nested list) by appending only the name with the following change:

```
playerNames.append(row[0])
```